# Open HTML as XHTML

Tags: html, xhtml

Having an `.html` file is it possible to force the browser to treat the contents as *XHTML*? I mean the file opened from both local or web location. Maybe some on-the-fly convertion or something like that?

*The background:*

Firefox and Opera supports natively [MathML](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) when the code is embedded in a *XHTML* file. I need to get a `.html` file with MathML that would be supported by the mentioned browsers properly.

Thank you for any support.

Comment: You need to make it clear that this is both **local** and **remote** that you want this behavior. I missed that twice.

Comment: You should know regardless of the content-type header and doctype your browser make still go into "Quarks" mode (and not XHTML mode) if your XHTML is not well formed and valid.

Comment: Not true. Browsers always use standards mode for documents parsed as XHTML. Doctype switching is only applied in tag soup parsing mode.

Answer (score 2):

For local files (see below if you are using a server):

Browsers generally only run off file extensions for determining if a local file is HTML or XHTML.

Your options:

- Rename the files
- Run a local webserver that can serve with an application/xhtml+xml content type
- Wait for HTML 5 support of inline SVG
- Use [JS to generate the SVG](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- Use symbolic links (if you are on *NIX) so you have both file names available
- Add a Doctype detection and parse mode switching feature to Firefox, it is open source (yes, I realize this isn't the most practical suggestion, that is why it is last)

---

For files served via HTTP:

Consult the manual to find out how to change the content type for a given file extension. For example, Apache can use the [AddType directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype).

Answer (score 0):

File extension has nothing to do in this case. The only thing that really matters is the `Content-Type` header. By default your webserver treat `.html` files, as `text/html`, but you should force it to send is as `application/xhtml+xml`.

If you're using any server-side language, you can do something like that (PHP example)

```
header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml');
```

If you're unable to use any programming language, then you can configure your webserver to treat `.html` files as XHTML (Apache, `.htaccess` example)

```
AddType application/xhtml+xml .html
```

#### Edit:

I didn't noticed that you're also trying to open XHTML from local file. Then file extension may be important - but David Dorward answer to that case.

Comment: application/xhtml+xml, not application/xml+xhtml